# how can I cut a string that contain "map" in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how can I cut a string that contain "map" in jquery/javascript

Example:
If i have a string

```
var stringName = "abc mapTest bbc";
```

How Can I cut the string by result only mapTest?

NOTE: like assume the stringName is not the fixed value, it could change to "mapTest asdasd asdd", "asdasd asfffd mapTest" and so on. and the "mapTest" will keep changing (e.g mapTest1, mapTest, mapTest5 and so on)

Comment: what should be ur output... can u show that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you want to remove `mapTest` (or `mapZZPQ` or whatever), or return only `mapTest` when you find `map`.  Here is code to do either:

```
var stringName = "123 abcmapdef 456";  // sample input

var hasMap = stringName.match(/\b\w*map\w*\b/);           // returns "abcmapdef"          
var hasNoMap = stringName.replace(/\b\w*map\w*\b/g, "");  // returns "123  456"
```

If you only want to match `"map"` at the beginning of word, remove the first `\w*` from the pattern, i.e. `/\bmap\w*\b/`.

Comment: word boundary matching (`\b`) would be better than `\w*`

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
var stringName = "abc mapTest bbc";
var m = stringName.match(/\bmap\w+\b/);
```

i.e. match a word boundary, "map" followed by one or more[*] alphanumerics, and another word boundary.

The result you want ("mapTest") will be in

```
m[0]
```

When there's a match, `String.match()` returns an array, the first element of which is the matched value.  If there's no match it'll return `null` instead.

[*] if "map" on its own should also match then change the `+` in the regexp to `*`.

Comment: +1 for `\b` improvement. I forgot about that. But I think that you need to add `g` at the end of the regex to get an array result.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
var result = stringName.split(" ");
var mapTest = result[1];
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var stringName = "abc mapTest bbc"; 

var patt1=/mapTest/gi;

var result = stringName.match(patt1);
```